# What is the "Duplicate Provider" error?

Tags: google-play-store, system-error, angry-birds

I have installed Angry birds from the official android market. I tried installing the Angry Birds Seasons free version today, and while installing I got a pop-up message saying "Duplicate provider" and the installation terminated. I am running ICS on Nexus S, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means something's wrong with the package setup. For your reference, here are a few links with more detailed information:

- [android duplicate provider authority - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078208/android-duplicate-provider-authority)
- [Android duplicate provider authority problem - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420130/android-duplicate-provider-authority-problem)
- [Angry Birds Seasons Summer Pignic Now Available | AngryBirdsNest](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-seasons-summer-pignic-now-available-for-iphone/) (search for "duplicate provider" on this page, should appear around the middle)
- [Duplicate provider authority error when installing K-9 mail - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/k-9-mail/rGWFlakYja0%5B1-25%5D)

Recommendation: Contact developer (for security reasons *both* developers, in case somebody faked the signature). It's most likely a copy-and-paste error during the packaging process, so the developer might release a fixed update soon.