# "Duplicate provider authority" error message when downloading apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I am trying to download an app on my tablet (running KitKat 4.4) but it keeps coming up with this error saying "duplicate provider authority".

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! If you add more information to your question (e.g. where you are downloading the app from, when the error message appears), you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

A provider authority appears to be similar to a package name, in that it must be unique<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189678/android-content-provider-authorities) [2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html)</sup>. Probably, the developer made a mistake when compiling the app<sup>[3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18953/what-is-the-duplicate-provider-error)</sup>, and if you contact them they'll release a fixed version.